# How to display text in html?

Tags: html

I have the following html which will only display the word `events` and not `Find An Event` or `Post An Event`. Why is this as all the words should be displaying on the page?

```html
<div class="lasvegas">
Events 
</div>



<div class="findanevent"><a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><div 
class="findanevent"><font size="3"><font 
color="white">Find an Event</font></font></div></a>



<div class="postanevent"><a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><div 
class="postanevent"><font size="3"><font 
color="white">Post an Event</font></font></div></a>
```

Basically I want `find an Event` and `Post an Event` in the same style and governed by the same css as `Events`.

The problem is that, if I put:

```
<div class="lasvegas">Events 


<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><div 
class="findanevent"><font size="3">Find an Event</font>. 
</div></a>

<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><div 
class="postanevent"><font size="3">Post an 
Event</font>. 
 </div></a>
```

Then it not only displays `find an event` and `post an event` in black but, on desktop, it doesn't separate the link destinations, so they both go to the same place.

So basically I want `Events` and `find an event` and `post an event` all in pink neon glow, with `find an event` and `post an event` slightly smaller than title `Events`

Please see https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Comment: Post the CSS, the problem is probably there.

Comment: I also just noticed that you have them both set to the color white. If your page is white then you wont see the text. ex `<font 
color="white">Find an Event</font>` & `<font 
color="white">Post an Event</font>` remove the `color="white"` or change it to the desired color. https://jsfiddle.net/3h6sxpoa/1/

Comment: @Rick Sibley https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AcEDjki.jpg You have `* {color: #000000}` this makes the default color black. Pretty sure the only way to overwrite the color is use something like `color: white!important`. Not recommended though. I would just fix the code  by dumping the `* {color: #000000}` and add the black color only to the elements that need it.

Comment: @Rick that's the thing. Even if I do important it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: But also, if i leave the div open after `events ` part of the css styling from events applies to `find an event` and etc....but part of it doesn't. The text still glows pink but the color is black.... Odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div class="lasvegas">
  Events 
</div>



<div class="findanevent"><a 
 href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><div 
 class="findanevent"><font size="3"><font 
 color="green">Find an Event</font></font></div></a>



<div class="postanevent"><a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><div 
class="postanevent"><font size="3"><font 
color="purple">Post an Event</font></font></div></a>
```

change your color to green:

Comment: If you want help make it easier for us to help you.  Post a snippet of what you have including your css.  You have a line in your css file * { color:black;} that needs to be deleted.  also, assign the css to your other two links and change the font size

Comment: hmm, all I can find is label[type="submit"]{ /* search button */
color: black;
}

Comment: look for * {
  color: #000000;
} it's in so-css-shapley.css

Comment: Would that be in my additional css?

Comment: I have two additional css boxes

Comment: Is there a way nullify it as itmay be difficult to find?

Comment: it is in your file so-css-shapley.css can you locate that file?

Comment: That's great. Looking in stylesheet css but it's massive...and don't have the ability to scan it as I'm on mobile. I designed the whole site on an old mobile phone :-) everything :-)don't have a computer...

Comment: here's the location https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/so-css/so-css-shapely.css  check out line 160

Comment: That worked. You absolute genius. Now just apply the css for `.lasvegas` to `. findanevent, `?

Comment: Basically, i want to ditch the other font and use this `font-face {
    font-family: 'neontubes';
    src: url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.eot');
    src: url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),

Comment: `      url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('https://bitbucket.org/kennethjensen/webfonts/raw/fc13c1cb430a0e9462da56fe3f421ff7af72db71/neontubes/neontubes-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`

Comment: Where would I put it and how would link it to existing css for `Events`

Comment: So added the previous css to my style.css and then added `neontubes` here: `min-height:100vh;
 
 background:
 #112
 url(//images.weserv.nl/url=i.imgur.com/6QJjYMe.jpg)
 center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0;
 
 }

.lasvegas {
font-family: 'neontubes', cursive;
font-size:80px;
border: none;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
text-align:`

Comment: It doesn't seek to have changed the font type though. I'm doing it because the other font face is obsolete, but it doesn't work. Why not? Thanks.

Comment: Also, neither `findanevent` or `postanevent` will display `inline-block` despite `important`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your updated question - the styling is governed by the CSS. If you want each div to have the same style, they should each have the same class, for example:

```
<div class="events">Events</div>

<div class="events">
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/">Find an Event</a>
</div>

<div class="events">
    <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/">Post an Event</a>
</div>
```

The `events` class would contain any shared styles in CSS. If you want to make the `Events` heading larger, you can add a second class to this div, where you could set the font-size to a larger size.